# Is it acceptable to read outside the bound of an array (string)?

Tags: delphi

I study a little the Delphi source code, and this look a little ugly for me (in system.pas, procedure ValLong) :

```
while True do
begin
  case S[I] of
    '0'..'9': Dig := Ord(S[I]) - Ord('0');
  else
    Break;
  end;
  if (Result < 0) or (Result > (High(Integer) div 10)) then
    Break;
  Result := Result*10 + Dig;
  Inc(I);
  Empty := False;
end;
```

As you can see the **only way to get out of the loop is to read outside the boundary of S** (a string). Do I miss something and this is an correct practice ?

Comment: It doesn't read beyond the allocated memory. A `string` has a null byte, after the last character, at the end of allocated memory. See [Internal_Data_Formats](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Internal_Data_Formats)

Comment: @TomBrunberg oOh ok, I understand, I was not aware of the last #0 outside the boudary. I guess it's for converting to pchar. so it's look good. anyway tweaking like this seam for me a dangerous way to go :(

Comment: Allow me to disagree. There's no tweaking, the null byte is a part of the structure, and there's nothing dangerous. It is as designed.

Comment: There's no tweaking there. This is standard use of a PChar for accessing strings. It's used in hundreds (if not more) places in the Delphi source, as well as many times when working with Windows API calls.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unicode strings, AnsiString and WideString types are always ending with a null character.

From [Internal Data Formats-Long String Types](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Internal_Data_Formats_(Delphi)#Long_String_Types):

> The NULL character at the end of a string memory block is automatically maintained by the compiler and the built-in string handling routines. This makes it possible to typecast a string directly to a null-terminated string.

So, it is safe to rely on the fact that these types are null terminated. The code example in the question is ok.

**Note:** I'm assuming range checking is off, since this code is from the RTL. Otherwise, it would have caused an exception when indexing the null character.